# Why did I receive this e-mail from the Sheffield UK Decision Making Centre?

Tags: visa

I am applying for a Tier 4 Visa, and have completed the biometrics appt and online application. I sent off all of my documents in a package at UPS through 2-Day Air mail along with a 2-Day air return label around 10 AM from LA which is to be sent to the VFS Global office in NY.

About an hour later at 11 AM, I received a strange e-mail stating:

“Dear Applicant,

Your online application has been received at the UK Decision Making Centre in Sheffield.

CUSTOMERS IN THE USA

If you enrolled your biometrics at a US Dept of Homeland Security Application Support Centre (ASC) then the processing time on your application will start as soon as we receive confirmation from the New York Scanning Hub that your documents have been received and uploaded to our system.
“

I don’t understand why I would’ve received this message, if I JUST sent off my application through the mail. What online application do they mean? Just the UK Visa and Immigration application form, that they might have access to? Is this normal to receive this before even sending off my documents application?

There’s no way my documents application would’ve been sent to NY and then Sheffield in one hour. Highly confused and slightly concerned.

If anyone understands this, it’d be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, 'tho I imagine that the NY > Sheffield leg could easily be done by email, and not by sending physical documents. As the physical documents you couriered from LA to NY couldn't have arrived even in NY so soon, I suspect the email was sent in error.

Comment: Thank you for your response... I think that you must be correct that it was an error. They can’t make decision without seeing my documents scanned from NY to Sheffield yet. So I guess just wait around 2 weeks to see any updates. Thanks!

Comment: *Where* did you apply? The official site? Show the URL.